# how to create translate function as a method usable for an element in array

Tags: php, laravel, function, model-view-controller

I have an array that has data about an exam, every exam has 1 type only from 4 types in all `[iq,math,geo,gen]` and I get it this way `{{ $exam->type }}` I only want to add translate method to the type, so when I write `$exam->type->translate()` I get the translated word, how the function structure would be and where should I write it, in `Exam` model or the controller of the page...

translate function:

```
function translate($word){
  return $word == "math" 
             ? "ماث" 
             : $word == "iq" 
             ? "آيكيو" 
             : $word == "geo"
             ? "هندسة"
             : $word == "gen"
             ? "شامل"
             : "غير معرّف"
}
```

Comment: Why write your own translate function if you can use the Laravel translation helpers `__('Whatever you want to translate')`?

Comment: yeah I know, but if you tried to translate gen, you'll get DNA's gen, but gen means general, and math means 'رياضيات' in Arabic but I want it to be 'ماث' which is the pronounce of the word in Arabic letters, it may seem weird but the audience understand this way :), so I'm not translating I'm converting you can say

Comment: The Laravel translation helpers use translation files, so you can put whatever you want. It's not that it automatically translates whatever you pass to the function. You define what the translations for words/sentences are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't nest ternaries like that. It's a mess to read and to resolve since you easily will get the precedence wrong (plus, since PHP 7.4, you need to group nested ternaries with parentheses, or you'll get a deprecation warning, or a fatal error from PHP 8)

If you rather do it manually (instead of using Laravel's translation feature, which probably would be recommended), you can make it easier by using an array:

```php
function translate($word)
{
    $words = [
        "math" => "ماث",
        "iq"   => "آيكيو", 
        "geo"  => "هندسة",
        "gen"  => "شامل",
    ];

    // Check if the word exists in the array and return it 
    // if it doesn't exist, return the default
    return $words[$word] ?? "غير معرّف";
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, I'll use this instead but my main question is how can I use it, or how can I make it a method

Comment: @Sarout - You can [extend blade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#extending-blade) to add your own directives you can use, or you can pass a custom class instance to your view that contains that method.